# É possível que o Rmarkdown carregue um código do R?

Tags: r, rmarkdown

Já tenho um código pronto no R e agora estou aprendendo o Rmarkdown.

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, existe alguma função que carrega o código em R no Rmarkdown que me permite usar as informações sem ter que passar o código no chunk do markdown?

Comment: Dê uma olhada na função `source()`.

Comment: Tem várias opções. Tem `source()` como já disseram ou você pode ver a `read_chunk()` se tiver que rodar o código aos poucos.

Comment: Muito obrigado @WillianVieira e JorgeMendes resolveu meu problema!

Comment: @WillianVieira pode postar alguma resposta para ajudar visitantes no futuro?

Comment: Ou @JorgeMendes ?